# How do I define the timeout for bootstrap actions on Amazon's Elastic MapReduce?

Tags: amazon-ec2, mapreduce

How do I change the timeout for bootstrap actions on Amazon's Elastic MapReduce?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=64568) (the first answer), the timeout for all bootstrapping actions is 45 minutes. I couldn't find any reference as to setting this timeout.